# CSS backdrop-filter works only if you DON'T set background-color to transparent

Tags: javascript, css, background-color

I've got a greyscale backdrop-filter applied to a `.cover` behind one of my overlaid menus. It always has a background color, but when it is `.on` I sometimes, with JavaScript, want to set the `.cover`'s background-color to an opaque black to darken the background, too.

I have the following CSS being applied to the cover:

```css
body {
    --darkMode: transparent;
}
.cover {
    background-color: #123456;
}
.cover.on {
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: grayscale(100%);
    backdrop-filter: grayscale(100%);
    background-color: var(--darkMode); /* Notable Line */
}
```

The JavaScript that sets the `--darkMode` variable is just `document.body.style.setProperty("--darkMode", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)");`

However, when darkMode is not enabled, and therefore the `.cover`'s background-color is `transparent` ***just like default***, the backdrop-filters don't work at all.

You can play around with this with [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/plettj/ohrqeay1/8/).

Thanks for any insights you might have, and have a splendid day, person who was willing to read this question.

EDIT 1: My apologies, the above code was not complete; I have updated to reflect my code more directly, and have added a JS fiddle so you can see it yourself.

EDIT 2: Turns out a solution is to just set the background-color to something like `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01)` instead of transparent.

Comment: > The backdrop-filter CSS property lets you apply graphical effects such as blurring or color shifting to the area behind an element. ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter ) If it's transparent, how can filter work or how do you know that it doesn't work because default most bottom element (`<body>`) is white.

Comment: Thanks for the point! However, the follow-up question is, since a background-color is transparent by default (https://cssreference.io/property/background-color), why does it work when you don't set the background-color at all, but not when you set it to transparent?

Comment: I don't see any CSS filter in the link you provide. It would be easier if you provide reproducible code for anyone to test and see the result.

Comment: `backdrop-filter` doesn’t work in all major browsers, namely Firefox.